# Custom redirector with htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess

How create a redirector like http://noref.li/#uhttp://yoururl.com

or

http://www.identi.li/u#http://google.com

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

is the question here how to pass the url as the hash rather than a param?

```
<script>
document.location = document.location.hash;
</script>
```

For the record if your goal is to get at the hash of the url for the redirect to, you need to do it on the client side, the hash content is never sent to the server.

Comment: This is what I understood he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged under PHP? Try

```
header('Location: http://www.identi.li/u#http://google.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tag inside your html file header.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20;url=http:www.redirected.com">
```

This will redirect after twenty seconds